# what are acceleration.x ,acceleration.y in didaccelerate delegate method

Tags: xcode

I have a doubt regarding the UIAccelerometer.

1. What is the units of acceleration.x?
2. How can I calculate the Velocity using UIAccelerometer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Unit is 1g = 9.81m/s^2, e.g. the acceleration of the earth gravity field.
2. Acceleration is the change in velocity. You can get the velocity at time t1 only if you know the velocity at time t0. Then

v(t1) = v(t0) + (a(t1) - g) * (t1-t0)

, assuming that t1 and t0 are the times of two consecutive measurements. Here v is the velocity vector, a the acceleration vector and g the gravity vector.

However, the accelerometers in the iOS devices have a lot of noise and are not particularly well suited to track velocity (or position). For large scale distances you have GPS. For small distances there is no reliable method.

Best, Peter.